# How do I change a character string randomly on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fonts

I need a javascript/jquery script that does the following:

I have a big letter (about 40px font size) in an h1 tag or div doesnt matter, lets say its the letter B. When I hover over it I want it to change to another random character from a list/array of characters that I specify (ie. "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"). How can I do this? PS. when I hover out it again changes randomly, so basically whenever my mouse goes over the current character it needs to change to a new character (ie. B then F then $ then 0 then s then f etc etc.)

Thanks :)

PS. I'd actually like it to be any unicode character, I work with fonts a lot and I will be manipulating glyphs. So does the list/pool look something like this then?
"±²·" etc. ?

Comment: Then get started on it.

Comment: Obligatory: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Just asking for the code, fully formed and ready to go is not appropriate for a question on Stack Overflow. Please read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and this article http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ that explains some of the reasoning behind why questions are closed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. If your div has an id of character, your javascript could look something like this:

```
var characters = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function changeCharacter() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(characters.length * Math.random());
    var randomCharacter = characters[randomIndex];
    $("#character").text(randomCharacter);
}
$("#character").mouseenter(changeCharacter);
$("#character").mouseleave(changeCharacter);
```

Example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EsQJ/1/

Comment: thanks dude! does just what i wanted! :)